# Chart.js pie chart overflowing div

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I'm having trouble getting a Chart.js (v2.6) pie chart to fit into a bootstrap div. The width is responsive, but the height overflows. I have the height set to `210px` with `statcard-fixed-height` as you can see in the fiddle. The box maintains that height but the chart does not.

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 m-b">
        <div id="new-old" class="statcard statcard-primary statcard-bg statcard-fixed-height-lg">
            <div class="p-a">
                <span class="statcard-desc">New vs. Returning Users</span>
                <canvas id="myPieChart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
result = [{
    label: "New Users",
    data: 48.8
}, {
    label: "Returning Users",
    data: 51.2
}];

var labels = [],
    data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    labels.push(result[i].label);
    data.push(result[i].data);
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'New vs Returning Users',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: ["#9F86FF", "#1BC98E"],
            lineTension: 0.1,
            data: data
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            labels: {
                fontColor: '#fff'
            }
        },
        elements: {
            arc: {
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        }
    }
});
ctx.height = 100;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3d6hqhc1/1/

**UPDATE:**

Simpler fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m80xxxv8/1/

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2422

Include a holder div and set maintainAspectRatio to false

`<div id="canvas-holder" >
   <canvas id="chart-canvase" />
</div>`

`var options = {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio : false
        };`

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap you chart into a div

```
#responsive-chart{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 m-b">
        <div id="new-old" class="statcard statcard-primary statcard-bg statcard-fixed-height-lg">
           <div class="p-a">
               <span class="statcard-desc">New vs. Returning Users</span>
                <div id="responsive-chart">
                    <canvas id="myPieChart"></canvas>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change height:100%, in the update of your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m80xxxv8/1/ it works for me!